# Why is my Kurtosis function not producing the same output as scipy.stats.kurtosis?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I have a homework problem in which I'm supposed to write a function for Kurtosis as descirbed here:

[image: Kurtosis, where theta is the standard deviation]

The theta in the denominator is the standard deviation (square-root of the variance) and the x-with-the-bar in the numerator is the mean of `x`.

I've implemented the function as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import kurtosis

testdata = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

def mean(obs):
    return (1. / len(obs)) * np.sum(obs)

def variance(obs):
    return (1. / len(obs)) * np.sum((obs - mean(obs)) ** 2)

def kurt(obs):
    num = np.sqrt((1. / len(obs)) * np.sum((obs - mean(obs)) ** 4))
    denom = variance(obs) ** 2  # avoid losing precision with np.sqrt call
    return num / denom
```

The first two functions, `mean` and `variance` were successfully cross-validated with `numpy.mean` and `numpy.var`, respectively.

I attempted to cross-validate `kurt` with the following statement:

```
>>> kurtosis(testdata) == kurt(testdata)
False
```

Here's the output of both kurtosis functions:

```
>>> kurtosis(testdata)  # scipy.stats
-1.3

>>> kurt(testdata)  # my crappy attempt
0.65192024052026476
```

Where did I go wrong?  Is `scipy.stats.kurtosis` doing something fancier than what's in the equation I've been given?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, [`scipy.stats.kurtosis()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kurtosis.html):

1. Computes *excess* kurtosis (i.e. subtracts 3 from the result).
2. Corrects for statistical biases (this affects some of the denominators).

Both behaviours are configurable through optional arguments to `scipy.stats.kurtosis()`.

Finally, the `np.sqrt()` call in your method is unnecessary since there's no square root in the formula. Once I remove it, the output of your function matches what I get from `kurtosis(testdata, False, False)`.

> I attempted to cross-validate kurt with the following statement

You shouldn't be comparing floating-point numbers for exact equality. Even if the mathematical formulae are the same, small differences in how they are translated into computer code could affect the result of the computation.

Finally, if you're going to be writing numerical code, I strongly recommend reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

P.S. This is the function I've used:

```
In [51]: def kurt(obs):
   ....:     num = np.sum((obs - mean(obs)) ** 4)/ len(obs)
   ....:     denom = variance(obs) ** 2  # avoid losing precision with np.sqrt call
   ....:     return num / denom
```

Comment: regarding the floating-point precision, shouldn't the floating point values (and their errors) correspond exactly?  Also, thanks for catching that obvious bug!  That looks like a silly copy/paste error on my part =/

Comment: Could you post the code in your answer?  I simply removed the call to `np.sqrt` in my `kurt` function, and called `scipy.stats.kurtosis(testdata, False, False)`, but I'm still getting vastly different outputs.  My function is outputting `1.70000000...`, wheras scipy's function is giving me `-1.3`.  What are you getting?  Did you have to modify anything else besides removing the square-root function?

Comment: @blz: Sure, I've added the code to my answer. BTW, 1.7 is correct. -1.3 is the **excess** (a.k.a. Fisher's) kurtosis, so you're not setting the scipy's `fisher` argument to `False`.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'll try setting it as a kwarg; maybe that's why I'm still getting excess kurtosis.