# Python suggestion how to improve my class using nested function

Tags: python, class, function, optimization, coding-style

I am working on my own class metric

```
import numpy as np

class Metric(object):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.min = min(args)
        self.max = max(args)
        self.median = np.percentile(args,50)
        self.avg = sum(args)*1.0/len(args)
        self.len = len(args)
        self.std = np.std(args)
        self.var = np.var(args)
        self.IQR = np.percentile(args,75)-np.percentile(args,25)
        self.relief_ratio = (self.avg-self.min)*1.0/(self.max-self.min)
```

i wish to nested a function to calculate Kurtosis without using `from scipy.stats import kurtosis`. Following this example the [Kurtosis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571198/why-is-my-kurtosis-function-not-producing-the-same-output-as-scipy-stats-kurtosi) formula is:

```
def avg(obs):
    return (1. / len(obs)) * np.sum(obs)

def variance(obs):
    return (1. / len(obs)) * np.sum((obs - avg(obs)) ** 2)

def kurt(obs):
    num = np.sum((obs - avg(obs)) ** 4)/ len(obs)
    denom = variance(obs) ** 2  # avoid losing precision with np.sqrt call
    return num / denom
```

my questions are:

1. Which is the right python style, do i need write `avg`, `variance`,
   and `kurt` outside the class or inside?
2. if inside which is the best style?

Answer (score 3):

Those aren't nested functions; they're just functions that call each other.  Nested functions are functions *containing* other functions.

I'd leave them outside.  These functions don't care about most of the stuff in your class, have simple arguments and return values that can be understood without the context of your class, and would be perfectly useful on lists of numbers independently of your class.  Why hide them away?

Comment: Dear @Eevee i am a brand new of class philosophy and i am learning right now. I wish understand the right philosophy  under the creation of a class object. Thanks for your suggestions.